# Cannot use args (type []string) as type []interface {}

Tags: go

my golang sqlite insert function. i'm using this package `"github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"`

```
func Insert(args ...string)(err error){
  db, err:=sql.Open("sqlite3","sqlite.db")
  if err !=nil {
    return
  }
  q, err := db.Prepare(args[0])
  if err !=nil{
    return
  }
  _,err = q.Exec(args[1:]...)
  return
 }
main (){
  err := Insert("INSERT INTO table(first,last) VALUES(?,?)","Nantha","nk")
  if err !=nil{
  fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
  }
}
```

i'm getting this error

> cannot use args (type []string) as type []interface {} in argument to
>   q.Exec

Comment: You have to convert `[]string` to `[]interface{}` before passing it to `Exec`. And the way to do that is to loop over the strings and add each one to a new slice of interface{}.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Comment: any other solution without using loop

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: @mkopriva He could use a recursive solution which formally isn't a loop ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, the function expects type `[]interface{}` but you're passing in a value of type `[]string`. You have to first convert `[]string` to `[]interface{}` before passing it to `Exec`. And the way to do that is to loop over the strings and add each one to a new slice of `interface{}`.

https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

---

As an alternative approach, you can change the `Insert` argument types.

```
func Insert(query string, args ...interface{}) (err error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "sqlite.db")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    q, err := db.Prepare(query)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = q.Exec(args...)
    return err
}

func main() {
    err := Insert("INSERT INTO table(first,last) VALUES(?,?)", "Nantha", "nk")
    if err !=nil{
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
}
```

---

Please note that you're using the `database/sql` package incorrectly. Many of the objects returned from that package's functions/methods need to be **closed** to release the underlying resources.

This is true for `*sql.DB` returned by `Open`, `*sql.Stmt` returned by `Prepare`, `*sql.Rows` returned by `Query`, etc.

So your function should look closer to something like this:

```
func Insert(query string, args ...interface{}) (err error) {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "sqlite.db")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer db.Close()

    q, err := db.Prepare(query)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer q.Close()

    _, err = q.Exec(args...)
    return err
}
```

---

Also note that [`sql.DB`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB) is reusable, that means that you don't have to `sql.Open` a new instance every time you need to talk to the database.

From the docs on Open:

> The returned DB is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and
>   maintains its own pool of idle connections. Thus, the Open function
>   should be called just once. It is rarely necessary to close a DB.

If you keep doing it the way you're doing it, openning a new `DB` every time you call `Insert` or any other function that needs to talk to the `DB`, your program will perform worse than if you had a single `DB` and have your functions reuse that.

Comment: v:= []interface{}{"nantha","nk"} -> Insert(q,v)
i'm getting unsupported type []interface {}, a slice of interface

Comment: @Nantha You don't need to do that, `Insert(q, "Nantha", "nk")` will still work, even after you change the `Insert` to `Insert(query string, args ...interface{})`

Comment: @Nantha and if you want to use `v := []interface{}{"nantha","nk"}`, you can do it like this `Insert(q, v...)`.

Comment: it's working :) thank you so much

Comment: sorry but this is ridiculous, i need to copy my string array/slice to interface array/slice because I wanted to write generic function that can accept any type?